# Google Identity API / GitKit - change domain on a production app

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

We are using GitKit API in production projects - and there is an urgent need to change the domain of one of our existing projects.

This is normally done under Google Cloud Console - in API Manager under "Identity Toolkit API" -> "Edit" link. Unfortunately, this link is gone - it was probably removed this week?!

We know the new projects should use Firebase Authentication (as announced on Google I/O this year) and we have started to work on upgrading our auth code and we are keen on using it in new projects.
But our existing production projects cannot be migrated easily!

We have not been alerted anyhow in advance, that "Edit" on existing projects will be disabled - and there is no deprecation date specified at https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/migrate-firebase or in the alert messages. As paying Google Apps customers we rely on many Google products. This is a very unpleasant surprise.

Is there any way how to restore the "Edit" for "Identity Toolkit API" for existing projects? As I said, we urgently need to adjust a domain of an existing production project. Any help from the Google engineers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a bug. Can you please reach out via the [Firebase troubleshooting contact form](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/?hl=en) with high urgency and mentioning to route this to "liujin"?

Please also include information about your project (like project number) as well as the configuration change you wanted to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. We have rolled out the fix, and the Identity Toolkit API setting page should work now.